# Choosing Firearms (With Replacement)

Tags: probability

In a shooting gallery there are 4 types of firearms. A practice shooter can choose 1 firearm 
at each shooting (with replacement). In a given day the shooter practices 8 shootings. What is the 
probability that in a given day he uses each of the 4 type of firearms at least once?

My work:

I chose to see this question as how many ways can I distribute 8 shots among 4 guns.
each gun has to receive at least 1 shot = P(each received one shot) + P(each received 2 shots) since there are 8 firings so the probability is $4^{-4} + 4^{-8}$, is this correct?

Any help would be appreciated

thanks

Comment: I think your idea to view it as distributing shots among the four guns is good. Can you count the total number of unique distribution of the shots? How can you then count the number of distributions that have at least one shot on each gun, using something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the day is done, write down the sequence of gun choices we made. There are $4^8$ possible sequences, all equally likely.

Now we count the number of *good* sequences, sequences that use all $4$ guns.
For our probability, we will divide the number of good sequences by $4^8$.

Let us instead count the number of *bad* sequences, sequences that do not use all the guns.

There are $3^8$ sequences that do not use gun A, $3^8$ that do not use gun B, and so on.

But the number $4\cdot 3^8$ counts twice, for example, the sequences that miss **both** A and B. There are $2^8$ such sequences, and $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to choose a pair of guns to be omitted. So from $4\cdot 3^8$ we subtract $\binom{4}{2}2^8$.

However, we have removed too many times the sequence that does not use A, B, or C, and all other same gun sequences. We need to add back $4$ to deal with that.

Thus the number of bad sequences is 
$$\binom{4}{1}3^8 -\binom{4}{2}2^8 +\binom{4}{3}1^8.$$

Here we used the Principle of Inclusion/Exclusion. For general information about this kind of problem, please see the Wikipedia article on [Stirling numbers of the second kind.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_number_of_the_second_kind)

**Remark:** Since the numbers are small, we can instead divide into cases. It is process that has to be done carefully. Think of the gun choices as a word of length $8$ from the alphabet A, B, C, D

One gun might be chosen $5$ times, and the others $1$ time each. The popular gun can be chosen in $\binom{4}{1}$ ways, and for each choice there are $\binom{8}{5}$ ways to choose *when* it is used. The remaining Slots can be filled in $3!$ ways, for a total of $\binom{4}{1}\binom{8}{5}3!$ ways.

One gun might be chosen $4$ times, another twice, and the other two once each,
Similar reasoning as in the paragraph above gives a count of $\binom{4}{1}\binom{8}{4}\binom{3}{1}\binom{4}{1}2!$.

One could continue, it is not *too* bad. However, the chance of leaving out some cases, or doing a small miscomputation somewhere, is high.