# When selecting with replacement, what's the probability that some items are never chosen?

Tags: probability

If we are selecting with replacement $n$ times, what's the probability that $a$ items are never selected?

To give a concrete example: imagine we're shooting 100 bullets randomly at a building with 60 windows (assuming each bullet will hit a window space). What's the probability that 10 windows will still be intact at the end?

Additionally, I don't think it changes the problem significantly, but what about the probability that *at least* 10 windows will still be intact?

I tried working it out using [this solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/445131/choosing-firearms-with-replacement) as a guide, but... well, I just couldn't figure out how to extend the logic to this situation. Also, the inclusion-exclusion approach seems increasingly cumbersome to work with when using large numbers; is there another way to think about this problem?

Thank you!

Edit: I just realized that for large numbers, this might be better thought of as an exponential decay problem... I'm going to try to work out the solution, but if someone else wants to beat me to it, feel free :)

Comment: Do you mean exactly $a$ items or at least $a$ items?

Comment: @joriki Either, or both, answers would be helpful. I think the two solutions should be related, right?